# How to parse an xml file encoded in iso-8859-1 with lxml?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Hello there i'm trying to parse a xml file encoded in ISO-8859-1 with lxml library with no success so far.

I opened the file to check the correct encoding using

```
f = open(file, mode = "r", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
print(f.read())
```

with a succesfull response

But when using the following code i get wrong characters:

```
from lxml import etree
import json
file = "test.xml"
parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding = "iso-8859-1")
tree = etree.parse(file, parser)
root = tree.getroot()
top_asset = root.find("Asset")
asset_metadata = top_asset.find("Metadata")
series_names = []
dict = {}
for app_data in asset_metadata.findall("App_Data"):
    if app_data.attrib["Name"].lower() == "asset_name":
        series_names.append(app_data.attrib["Value"])
        key = app_data.attrib["Name"].lower()
        value = series_names
        dict[key] = value
print(json.dumps(dict,indent = 2))
```

I get the following output:

```
{"asset_name": [
    "Todo en 90 d\u00edas: Antes del viaje",
    "90 Day Fiance: Before the 90 Days"
  ]}
```

I tried opening the file with the first code and then use `etree.fromstring(f)` but since the first line of the xml file is this `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` i get an error when trying to parse.
If i remove that specific line i can parse it but get the same response with the wrong characters

Here is the portion of the xml file which has the characters with issues:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ADI>
    <Asset>
        <Metadata>
            <App_Data Value="Todo en 90 días: Antes del viaje" Name="Asset_Name" App="MOD"/>
            <App_Data Value="90 Day Fiance: Before the 90 Days" Name="Asset_Name" App="MOD"/>
        </Metadata>
```

I checked the entire file in https://validator.w3.org/ and the output is the following:

> Warning: Documents encoded as windows-1252 are often mislabeled as
> ISO-8859-1, which is the declared encoding of this document.
>
> At line 1, column 41

Tried both `iso-8859-1` and `windows-1252` encodings as `XMLParser` parameters.

Comment: When I try parsing a iso-8859-1 encoded xml file with `lxml` with the first line as shown it seems to work fine. Please provide a [mre] including a sample input file.

Comment: @martineau i edited the question adding the requested information, please if you need any more specifics don't hesitate to ask for them

Comment: That's much better, but still not runnable (so not a [mre]). For example, what are `root`, `series_names`, and `dict`? (The latter is the name of a built-in, btw).

Comment: Please include all `import` lines and be sure code is runnable from empty Python session using sample provided.

Comment: should be runnable now, sorry for the mistakes

Comment: @Parfait any breakthrough here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me, that encoding is lost on `json.dumps()` stage. I would try to add `ensure_ascii` parameter:

```
print(json.dumps(dict, indent = 2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Comment: That solved the issue for me! Thanks a lot i thought i was doing something wrong with the lxml library